# Need help summing all even numbers in a given Fibonacci sequence (Project Euler)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, fibonacci

I'm doing Problem 232. Project Euler: Problem 2, Sum of even Fibonacci on Cody. I need to sum all even terms in a Fibonacci sequence with a given Fibonacci number. I pass 3/4 tests but the final test evades me. This is the code that I have written:

```
function y = euler002(x)
f(1) = 1;
f(2) = 2;
n = 10^5;
for i = 3:n-2
    f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2);
    if f(end) > x
        break
    else
        continue
    end   
end

idx = rem(f, 2) == 0;
y = sum(f(idx))     
end
```

So I'm constructing the Fibonacci sequence in f and then extracting and summing the even Fibonacci numbers in the sequence.

In the final test, we are given x = 666576 and the sum should evaluate to 257114. However, I'm getting it to be 1089154.

Comment: You are including `f(i)` in your array *before* you check whether you've exceeded the value of `x` or not. The last value generated in your sequence is `832040`, which is the difference between your answer and the expected answer.

Comment: @beaker Thanks for the answer, somehow I messed up the calculation of the difference in answers. At first I tried to begin the for loop with the if statement but that didn't work, so my solution was to include ```f(end) = 0``` in the if statement, but I assume there's a better way of doing it? I guess it would be prefered to not include the value in the array at all

Comment: That will work, putting it just before the `break`. It might be a bit cleaner to create a temporary variable, say `f = f(i-1) + f(i-2)` and then only add that to the array in the `else` clause.

Comment: But tbh, I wouldn't use an array at all, I'd just keep the 2 previous values and calculate the current `f` and add to the result `y` if the value is less than `x` and is even.